# Django change wrong column name in DB

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

in my Database (psql) I've got a table named `offers_offer` and inside that there is an column named `offer_name`, which is wrong, because it should actually be just `name`. I don't know why it has this name, but due to this I can't load any fixtures or create a new object, because I always receive the error that `name` wasn't found (obviously).

Now my model looks like this:

```
class Offer(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(default="", verbose_name='Offer Name', blank=False, max_length=255)
   (some other fields...)
```

and my ONLY initial migration looks like this:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.utils.timezone


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('crm', '0007_make_gender_mandatory'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Offer',
            fields=[
                ('name', models.CharField(default='', max_length=255, verbose_name='Offer Name')),
                (every other field...)
                ],
            options={
                (some options...)
            },
        ),
    ]
```

So I don't really know why it's named `offer_name` in my db, while this was created to have `name` as field name.

Anyway I tried to fix that by making a new migration like:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('offers', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='offer',
            name='offer_name',
            field=models.CharField(default='', db_column=b'offer_name', max_length=255, verbose_name='Offer Name'),
        ),
        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='offer',
            old_name='offer_name',
            new_name='name',
        ),
    ]
```

But if I do that, I just get a FieldDoesNotExist Error which states me that `django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: Offer has no field named 'offer_name'`

So does someone know a good way to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the model to accomodate for your custom column with the `db_column` argument like so:

```
name = models.CharField(default="", verbose_name='Offer Name', blank=False, max_length=255, db_column="offer_name")
```

To elaborate a little bit more: The `db_colum` parameter can be used with every default django field. When it is used django disregards it`s default naming scheme and just looks up whatever name you passed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was happening because I had initially put the RenameField in the previous (not yet committed to repo, but already applied) migration, and even though that one had been applied, Django seems to parse all of the dependency migrations logically and decided that the rename had already happened.